# How to make UITextField padding

Tags: swift

I have an Swift app. To make padding I wrote this code:

```
class TextField: UITextField {

let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 5)

override open func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
}

override open func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
}

override open func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
}
```

But today I converted my project to Swift 4.2 and now I have an error:

> 'UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect' has been replaced by instance method 'CGRect.inset(by:)'

How can I fix it?

Comment: `UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)` => `bounds.inset(by: padding)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace `UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)` by `bounds.inset(by: padding)`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!!!